# How the code gets to the next step only when i press the enter key in c++ (Thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop, enter

I saw the following code on the internet as

```
DWORD qThreadID;
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadFn, &uiCounter, 0, &qThreadID);

// Loop until the user enters 'q'
char cChar = ' ';
while (cChar != 'q') {
    cout << uiCounter << endl;
    cChar = (char)getchar();
}
```

how does the keypress event "Enter" works on it?
(when i debug it except for the press of "Enter" no other keypress functionality works  )
Thanks

Comment: When you are using C runtime library functions within an MT application, you should prefer `_beginthreadex` instead of `CreateThread` for thread management. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getchar()` reads from standard in, which is buffered, both in the
library and in the OS.  The usual OS's won't return from a read on a
console device until enter is entered; they support command line
editing, and require the enter key to finalize the input.

Comment: So do i consider the enter event as the default?

Comment: As the default for what?  `getchar()` will return whatever is typed in at the keyboard (supposing that standard in is connected to the keyboard), one character at a time.  Your program, however, doesn't get any characters until there is a complete line.  It's possible to read the keyboard one key at a time, but you need an additional library (like ncurses) or system dependent code to do so.  And the model behind `getchar()` is a stream of characters, not events.

Answer (score 1):

getchar() reads a single character of input.

However, your terminal likely does line buffering on the input, no input is sent to your program until you hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Because `enter` enters a `\n` which will be interpreted as `EOF` as the command line will think this is the end of user input and `getChar()` is trying to reading a single character buffer from this stream so nothing is returned if you simply press `enter` without entering characters before it, see msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5231d02a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: As getchar() is trying to read a single character buffer so if i instead of "Enter" i press one of the arrow keys wont that work or is it a default for the getchar() to accept enter(\n) as a defualt/non changeble entity

Comment: `\n` is __not__ interpreted as end of file, and is _not_ the end of user input.  Under Unix, a control-D is interpreted as end of file, and I believe that under Windows, a control-Z works similarly.

Comment: @jameswhitehurst Under Windows, at least in a console window, the arrow keys are intercepted by the OS, and don't show up in your program.  (But I'm sure there are ways of changing this.)  That's one of the reasons why no input is passed on until a newline is entered; you can use up arrow to bring up the previous line, then edit it, and on enter, those will be the characters sent on to your program.